The Frobenius Endomorphism is Surjective iff the field is perfect
I'm taking a Galois theory class right now. I've read and understood the proof that the Frobenius endomorphism is surjective iff the field is perfect (working in characteristic $p$). But it just feels like a weird trick to me. I don't see the connection between these two concepts. Can someone provide me with more intuition, maybe using a concrete example? I guess I just want more intuition for the Frobenius endomorphism -- it just feels very random.

See what happens when the $p$th power map on a  field $K$ with characteristic $p$ is not surjective: if $K$ contains an $a$ that is not a $p$th power in $K$ then $x^p - a$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ and this polynomial is never separable in characteristic $p$ (in fact any polynomial in $K[x^p]$ is inseparable in characteristic $p$). So in order that a  field with characteristic $p$ be perfect it is necessary that the $p$th power map on the field be surjective.  As  far as intuition is concerned, I think that's enough.
